# bash script does not work when called from PHP file?

Tags: php, bash, cloud-foundry

I am trying to run a bash script from the web using php exec() method. The same bash script when ran from the terminal ./test.sh works fine executes all the command without any error. But when i try to run it from the command line it would absolutely not work. They both are in the same location. I have even give chmod 777 permission to that file.

Commnads like ls , pwd etc work but cf isn't working ?

test.sh

```
/usr/bin/cf login -a https://api.stage1.ng.bluemix.net -o jetmak@ca.blue.com -s dev -u jenk@ca.blue.com -p pass22
/usr/bin/cf api
/usr/bin/cf
```

executeshellfromphp.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$bluemixid = $_POST['bluemixid'];
$bluemixpwd = $_POST['bluemixpswd'];
$env =  $_POST['env'];
$restart =  $_POST['action'];

$result =shell_exec('sh /var/www/shellscriptphp/test.sh    '.$env.'    '.$restart.'    '.$bluemixid.'  '.$bluemixpwd.'   ');
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
exit();
```

Error:

```
FAILED
Config error: Error writing to manifest file:.cf/config.json
open .cf/config.json: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Maybe the `cf` command isn't in the webserver's `$PATH`?

Comment: Try putting the full pathname of the `cf` command into the script.

Comment: Hi Barmar did try that getting the following error Config error: Error writing to manifest file:.cf/config.json. The same when ran from terminal runs without any error.

Comment: if i use shell_exec it would throw that error, if i use exec() it would not do anything.

Comment: Does the webserver userid have a `.cf` directory in its home directory?

Comment: that was exactly the problem i created .cf myself it works like a charm now thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Given that the command arguments come in externally via POST, you should really escape them via `escapeshellarg`. e.g.: `$bluemixid = escapeshellarg($_POST['bluemixid']);`